# See what handled a routed event

Tags: wpf, routed-events

Basically we have a huge project, and we have an event handler that sometimes is triggered and some others it isn't. I think this is because somewhere in the jungle of code, we're handling that event, so it doesn't bubble up to where we need it. Is there anyway to find out where is it being handled?

Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a real problem, a specific question, and I need a solution. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: What event is this? A custom event?

Comment: It's a routed event, LeftMouseButtonDown.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use Snoop..... there is an event Tab that tells us where the event is bubbled to and where its handled...